# Floating Objects in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I found this code on a web tutorial to make objects float on water in Unity:

```
RequireComponent (typeof (Rigidbody))]
public class ObjectFloatScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public float waterLevel = 0.0f;
    public float floatThreshold = 2.0f;
    public float waterDensity = 0.125f;
    public float downForce = 4.0f;

    private float forceFactor;
    private Vector3 floatForce;

    void FixedUpdate () {
        forceFactor = 1.0f - ((transform.position.y - waterLevel) / floatThreshold);

        if (forceFactor > 0.0f) {
            floatForce = -Physics.gravity * GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().mass * (forceFactor - GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity.y * waterDensity);
            
            GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().AddForceAtPosition (floatForce, transform.position);
        }
    }
}
```

What I don't Understand is the relationship between the Rigidbody.velocity.y and the water density ? Can someone help ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like some kind of "belly flop" factor :)

Only having `-gravity * mass` would result in a force perfectly countering the gravitation force on the object, stopping it instantly.

By scaling this force down by `velocity.y * waterDensity`, it will reduce this countering force, based on the entry velocity, simulating some kind of "water friction" as the object enters the water.

Cheers!